# could not save after selecting new HDP version for upgrade - is it a bug?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, ambari

We perform the following steps - ( from ambari GUI )

Admin – stack and versions -> version a manage version a OK a register version a register version

I select the button "HDP-2.6" to add new version and browses the VDF file – ( VDF was download from - http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.6.4.0/HDP-2.6.4.0-91.xml )

So now we have the new version

I select the local repo and add the repo PATH as the following 
But when I click oin save , save not affected at all , and save action does not activated
Please advise why , ? what  could be the problem

Comment: Looks like any screenshots are missing

Answer (score 0):

I used a trick to work around. 
First I saved (registered) with public repo and baseurls. 
Then with the stack definition file I modified stack and put my local urls.

As far as I understand, the main problem is, we can't see the build number while we register new stack. I think version definition file helps. In definition file, be sure you replace definition base urls with your local ones.